# Proguard corrupts drawable files

Tags: android, proguard

I have strange issue with proguard, somehow it breaks my valid drawable file. Without proguard drawable shows ok. Is proguard supposed to minify xml drawables?

**drawable/wide_btn_round_white.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="25dip" />
            <padding android:bottom="10dp"/>
            <padding android:top="10dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorOrangeGetStarted" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

becomes like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<x />
```

**build.gradle**:

```
release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

**proguard-rules.pro**:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @com.squareup.otto.Subscribe public *;
    @com.squareup.otto.Produce public *;
}
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
-keep class com.stripe.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.myapp.services.http.** {
    <fields>;
}
-keepclassmembers class com.myapp.services.ws.** {
    <fields>;
}
-keepclassmembers class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    <fields>;
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

**EDIT**:
This issue happens because of `shrinkResources`. It obfuscates all drawables that are specified ONLY in `style.xml`.
So for example if I have a button that has `style="@style/MyStyle"` and in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MyStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/wide_btn_round_white</it‌​em>
</style>.
```

`wide_btn_round_white.xml` is gonna be broken. But if I specify background directly on button everything would work OK. According wiki i can create  `app/src/main/res/values/keep.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:keep="@drawable/wide_btn_round_white" />
```

But this thing doesn't work. As I understand it only specifies that this file shouldn't be removed.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Best regard,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general Proguard does not work on xml files, only Java. So I think your build is some how corrupting your file. Perhaps opening a new project and copy there your source and the .git file(if you got one) will help

The other thing could be [Android shrink resources](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#shrink-resources), so try setting shrinkResources to false and see if it helps. If it does, use [tools:keep](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#keep-resources) to keep your problematic resources away from shrinker.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@layout/l_used*_c,@layout/l_used_a,@layout/l_used_b*"
    tools:discard="@layout/unused2" />
```

Comment: Ty, the issue was because of `shrinkResources`,  It obfuscates all drawables that are specified ONLY in `style.xml`. So I had a button that had `style="@style/MyStyle"` and in styles.xml: `<style name="MyStyle"><item name="android:background">@drawable/wide_btn_round_white</item></style>`. If I move the place where I specify `background` from styles direct to component attribute it works OK. But I have a lot of drawables that are specified in `styles.xml`. Any way I can fix this instead of manually listing all files in `tools:keep`?

Comment: I also tried to create file `app/src/main/res/values/keep.xml` with content: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@drawable/wide_btn_round_white" />`. The file gets corrupted anyway.