# ShrinkResources minifies drawables specified from styles.xml

Tags: android, gradle, shrinkresources

I'm having a strange issue with [shrinkResources](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) . If I specify background to my drawable directly via attribute it works OK. But If I move it to style, shrinkResources starts to minify them, thinking that they are not used. It's not like I concatenate drawable file name in runtime which is hard to detect. It's a very broad case from my opinion.

Also I know that I can list all of my drawable in `keep.xml` which prevents them from shrinking. But I have a lot of files and I plan to add them in the future as well which could lead to bugs in release (if I forget to add them). Is there another workaround?

**styles.xml**:

```
<style name="MyStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_drawable</item>
</style>
```

**my_layout.xml**:

```
<Button style="@style/MyStyle" ... />
```

**my_drawable.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="25dip" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**`./gradlew assembleRelease --info`**:

```
Skipped unused resource res/drawable/my_drawable.xml: 1348 bytes (replaced with small dummy file of size 104 bytes)
```

and **my_drawable.xml** becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<x />
```

For the sake of argument I specified:
**app/src/main/res/keep.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:shrinkMode="safe" />
```

Comment: Won't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880195/proguard-corrupts-drawable-files) help you?